# Flow destructuring of union type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I had a flow array typed with an object with one optional field. Then I decided that instead of an optional prop what I really want is an array of objects not containing that property or all the elements containing such property, so I switched to a union type.

The problem is that this makes destructuring of such prop impossible, and forces me to take some workarounds that will have runtime penalty. Here is an example of the sum type:

```js
type tab<T> =
  | { label: string }
  | { label: string, value: T }
```

This is what I can not do:

```
tabs.map(({ label, badge, value }, idx) => {
          callSomeFun(value || idx)
})
```

However, this works fine:

```
tabs.map(({ label, badge, ...tab }, idx) => {
          const value = tab.value || idx
          callSomeFun(value)
})
```

That object rest will have some extra runtime penalty and it adds a totally superfluous variable allocation.

Also because of this, some other parts of the code get an inferred type of mixed, which in runtime is not correct because I'm just "oring" them:

```
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(tabs[0].value || initialTab)
```

activeTab becomes of mixed type

Is there a better way of doing this while ensuring the type safety of having the prop on all items or no one?

Comment: Have you tried to add an explicit annotation to map function arguments, like the following:
`tabs.map(({ label, badge, value }: {label: string, badge: string, value?: number}, idx) => {
          callSomeFun(value || idx)
})`

Comment: Seems to work in Flow Try, but maybe some context is missing from the question: https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBMCGBGAeAKgPigXgFBSgHygG8oAbBCEgLigGdgAnASwDsBzKAXx3yNPKtoMWrADRQAbrBIBXCNWScsWAMYB7ZnRgIamKAG1iZeBWoByU2PiwAJqzlRzHALoBuJXHg0AdAFtYYAAoAw35LGzsxSRloDmpCIxNBJjYw23s6ZNEJKVkAfmpmaR9jeg4xRmsADwBKTHRCblwmpuUpEgBlVR8IADFpZgCo2XwCCpqsDmqlNQ1gKFaSDq7e-t0AmmXajHqOIA